# unable to use client certificate(no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, soap, ssl-certificate

I am trying to make a SOAP call to a server using CURL as belows.

The Requirement is

> We need to pass the ssl certificate and pass the Username and Password

```
    $ssl = "ssl_file_relative_address.pem";
    $pub_ssl_password = 'mynameiskhan';
    //Get the data
    $data = the_data_xml.xml;
    //Get the WSDL Address
    $wsdl = "address/to/wsdl?parameter=value";
    $soapUser = "Username";  //  username
    $soapPassword = "password"; // password

    $options = [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_URL => $wsdl,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $ssl,
        //CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $pub_ssl_password,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $soapUser.":".$soapPassword,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //curl_close($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print curl_error($ch); 
    }
```

I'm getting the following Error from CURL : unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

What is it that I'm doing Wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Solution. It required an intermediate CA Certificate.
The Solution is

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-type: application/json'],
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://address/to/service?param=value',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => getcwd()."\cacert.pem",
    URLOPT_SSLCERT => getcwd().'\cert.pem',
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => 'ssl_password',
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $soapUser.":".$soapPassword,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print curl_error($ch); 
}else{
    print_r($response);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Do not forget to mention the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to its content type, it is important.
Also download the intermediate certificate from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. It contains all the valid CA's.

Thanks @drew010 for help.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a client authentication certificate using `CURLOPT_SSLCERT`, the PEM file should contain a `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line followed by the certificate.

You also need to supply cURL with the corresponding private key to the certificate using `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` which is a file beginning with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.

If the private key is in `ssl_file_relative_address.pem`, then try copying the private key to a separate file.

If the private key is encrypted, you can specify the password using `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`.

Comment: The ssl certicate has a password only if its used in .pfx format. I've tried using your suggesstions, but still the same error.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding private key? `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` ?

Comment: Yes... I've... And as you said I've made a separate file of the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and passed it in CURLOPT_SSLKEY...

Comment: Is your version of cURL built with CyaSSL as opposed to OpenSSL?

Comment: The .pem certificate (ssl_file_relative_address.pem) contains all the certificate and private key... By the way I'm using XAMPP (PHP, Mysql, Apache)...

Comment: I ask about the SSL engine cURL is using because the only reference I can find to that error message is regarding CyaSSL (which I'm not very familiar with) and OpenSSL is not being used.  Is the private key encrypted or not?

Comment: The private key in PEM format could be encrypted, but it'd begin with `----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.  Is the exact error message you're getting `unable to use client certificate (no key or wrong pass phrase?)`?  As far as I can tell this is coming from [here](https://github.com/cyassl/cyassl/blob/b62dc8ab22ab5bd2ada800b8a0caaaebf01205b6/src/ssl.c#L2966).  It seems cURL is built using CyaSSL which has a similar interface to OpenSSL.  Is the private key maybe not readable by the web server user?  Does it have tight permissions like 400 or 600?

Comment: The CURL is build in OpenSSL/0.9.8y

Comment: I looked at older versions of cURL and they use this error message with OpenSSL, but not in more recent versions.  I'd still recommend storing the private key separately and providing it with `CURLOPT_SSLKEY`.  Is the CA/Root certificate for the generated client certificate in the PEM file?  I think it might be necessary.  Docs say `The certificates must be in PEM format and must be sorted starting with the subject's certificate (actual client or server certificate), followed by intermediate CA certificates if applicable, and ending at the highest level (root) CA`.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, I'd suggest updating cURL and moving to OpenSSL 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 if possible.